# Is "ein Herz wie das meine" an antiquated or colloquial use of the possesive pronoun?

Tags: possessive-pronoun

I am confused by the use of **meine** in this quote from *Die Leiden des jungen Werther*

> Waren nicht meine übrigen Verbindungen recht ausgesucht vom Schicksal, um **ein Herz wie das meine** zu ängstigen?

I take **ein Herz wie das meine** to mean **a heart such as mine**.

If **meine** refers to **Herz** shouldn't it be in the **accusative neuter**?

> ein Herz wie das meinem

Comment: `wie das meinem` is neither accusative nor right, it is a mix with dative and wrong. I cannot find any "sounds odd/old/wrong" on your quote from Goethe. just the entire way of speaking in this book is a bit "gestelzt".

Answer (score 15):

No. It's perfectly right. You are also right supposing that the case is accusative and the gender neuter. You are wrong, however, using *meinem* (is dative).

In the [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/mein)
[image] table, cf. *Nicht-attributiv, mit Artikel*,  you'll find agreement with Goethe's text. It's probably another register (*gestelzt*) but definitely not wrong (nor colloquial).

Comment: As @ShegitBrahm pointed out in their comment, it sounds "gestelzt". In common language, one would use "ein Herz wie meines".

Answer (score 7):

This use is as much antiquated as it is lyrical. It definitively is not colloquial. Some may use that occasionally but its by far not the norm.

Answer (score 5):

In your example, *meine* is a possessive adjective with a regular weak ending *-e* (just as in *das kranke Herz*). The more modern form would be

> ein Herz **wie meins**

with a neuter possessive pronoun (ending *-s*). Personally, I do find the combination of definite article and possessive adjective old-fashioned. Note that these adjectives can have *-ig* appended to them.

> daß grade Athen der Ort war wo ein Geist wie **der seinige** sich aufs herrlichste entwickeln mußte ([Quelle](https://archive.org/details/untersuchungenb00krgoog/page/n48?q=%22wie+der+seinige%22))

Comment: Goethe selbst hat diese Form in *Prometheus* verwendet: „...Ein Ohr, zu hören meine Klage,
**Ein Herz wie meins**,
Sich des Bedrängten zu erbarmen...”