# How do "attributiv" and "nicht attributiv" work?

Tags: declension, possessive-pronoun

Looking at the table for declension of "mein" on Wiktionary, it has separate tables for:
- attributiv (vor Substantiv)
- nicht attributiv, ohne Artikel
- nicht attributiv, mit Artikel

Could you give example sentences where the different uses would apply? I have also read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_declension#Attributive_adjectives which talks about strong, weak and mixed declension attributive adjectives, and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_adjectives which explains in general what an attributive adjective is, but I can't understand what a non-attributive use of "mein" would be, or why one would ever have an article.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wiktionary is a bit of a mess here. Usually, attributive vs. non-attributive is a distinction made for adjectives. Attributive adjectives accompany a noun and show agreement, non-attributive adjectives are used as predicatives or adverbs and do not show agreement. Also note that *am* + *-en* in the superlative only occurs in the non-attributive use.

> *attributive:* das **neue** Auto, die **beste** Idee
>   *non-attributive:* Das Auto ist **neu**. Diese Idee finde ich **am besten**.

Wiktionary's page for [mein](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/mein) uses "non-attributive" to indicate that there is no noun present. This subsumes two grammatically quite different cases:

> *possessive pronoun:* Dein Wortschatz ist größer als **meiner**.
>   *possessive adjective:* Dein Wortschatz ist größer als **der meine**.

In the first example, *meiner* is a possessive pronoun which shows anaphoric agreement with *Wortschatz*; in the second *meine* is a possessive adjective, with weak inflection triggered by the definite article *der*.

What Wiktionary calls "attributive" is the possessive article.

> *possessive article*: Dein Wortschatz ist größer als **mein Wortschatz**.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I was completely unfamiliar with the "Dein Wortschatz ist größer als der meine" form. That makes much more sense now.

Comment: @Vicky We actually just had a [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/50821/is-ein-herz-wie-das-meine-an-antiquated-or-colloquial-use-of-the-possesive-pro) about this. I think it should be considered old-fashioned.

Comment: I saw that question in HNQ which was actually why I was reading the Wiktionary page in the first place! My German is best described as “rusty” but my son is learning it now and I am trying to get it back so I can help him.